Flowbite React accordion не открывает все элементы по умолчанию, что делать?
Как сделать по умолчанию все открытые панели у аккордеона?
const ElementAccordion: React.FC<Props> = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-[95%] mx-auto mt-4">
      <Accordion
        flush 
        alwaysOpen
        className="border-none p-0"
      >
        {children}
      </Accordion>
    </div>
  );
};

const ContentAccordion:  React.FC<Props> = ({ items })  => {

  return (
    <ElementAccordion>
      {items.map((item, index) => (
        <Accordion.Panel
          key={index}
          isOpen={true}
          className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 rounded-lg shadow-md overflow-hidden w-[100%]"
        >
          <Accordion.Title className="text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400 hover:bg-[#EDEFF4] bg-gray-100 h-10 border-none mb-5">
            {item.title}
          </Accordion.Title>
          <Accordion.Content className="border-none p-0">
            {item.content}
          </Accordion.Content>
        </Accordion.Panel>
      ))}
    </ElementAccordion>
  );
};


Помимо isOpen={true} пробовал индекс подставлять и прочее. Ничего не вышло.
Открыто только 1, остальные 3 закрыты.
